# A tank contains 100 kg of salt and 2000 L of water.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> A tank contains $100\;\text{kg}$ of salt and $2000\;\text{L}$ of water. Pure water enters a tank at the rate $10 \;\text{L/min}$. The solution is mixed and drains from the tank at the rate $13 \;\text{L/min}$.
>
> Let $y$ be the number of $\text{kg}$ of salt in the tank after $t$ minutes.

I am getting
$$
  \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{-13}{2000}y + \frac{10}{2000}t
$$
but I cannot figure out why this is not correct. Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried? Also, you should read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960).

Comment: i having trouble starting.... i think that dy/dt might be along the lines of dy/dt=10-13/2000... but i am not getting that right

Comment: i am not sure what they are wanting for the initial condition part though

Comment: i have figured out y(0)=100 because that is original kg of salt

Comment: still am not getting dy/dt tho. I thought it might be -13/2000y+10/2000t but it is not

Comment: You should edit your original post to include the progress you have made here in the comments. (the edit will give you post a bump)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!